# График highcharts показывать на сайте как jpg

Tags: highcharts, jpeg

highcharts - классная библиотека для построения графиков. Но я так и не понял , можно ли выводить график на HTML страницу как jpg ?

Экспорт по кнопке в графике у меня есть, но хотелось бы спрятать данные из которых строиться график, это возможно?

т.е. надо чтобы график открывался типа так `<img src="">`, это возможно?

Comment: а в чем смысл картинки то?

Comment: чтобы вставлять график в rss ленту

Answer (score 0):

Пример с [офф. документации](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/index)

```js
$(function() {

  var exportUrl = 'https://export.highcharts.com/';

  var optionsStr = JSON.stringify({
      "xAxis": {
        "categories": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]
      },
      "series": [{
        "data": [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]
      }]
    }),
    dataString = encodeURI('async=true&type=jpeg&width=400&options=' + optionsStr);

  if (window.XDomainRequest) {
    var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
    xdr.open("post", exportUrl + '?' + dataString);
    xdr.send();
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: dataString,
      url: exportUrl,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#container').html('<img src="' + exportUrl + data + '"/>');
      }
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Если вам прям очень хочется спрятать данные графика то вы берёте ссылку, загружаете эту картингу себе на сервер и у вас уже будет картинка без данных

Comment: Спасибо, но это не то. Об этом я знаю и так. У меня не статичные графики, они меняются каждый день (каждый день появляется новая цифра), не буду же я руками каждый день картинку скачивать и менять...

Comment: До этого использовал библиотеку jpgraph (там на лету картинки строились) , но на php 7.3 она перестала работать, поэтому перешел на эту

Comment: зачем руками если для этого можно cron настроить и сервак сам всё будет менять?

Comment: @InDevX и чего вы в кроне напишите, интересно?

Comment: @hibinyru заявлена работа с пхп <=7.4. обновить может надо было просто?

Comment: @teran job ежедневный, который будет запускать файл, который, в свою очередь, будет актуализировать данные в "таблице с картинками"

Comment: @InDevX а все. понял о чем речь. вы бы ссылку на документацию нормально привели, на конкретику а не на общую страницу.. в том числе на этот сервис "экспорта".